# AJAX post to Express returns no data to req.query (yes there is the same q but nothing works)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, express

this is my set up. However when I send data through the ajax the body is empty. On chrome under network I see the post and the content, with a correct payload:

[image: request]

```
{"EventName":"asd","PrivacyLevel":1,"TypeInt":1,"ExpectedDate":"asd","Desc":"asd","Down":0,"Up":0,"PostCode":"","Address":"","ID":""}
```

Most people say its the body parser, I have placed the parsers above the app.use(app.router) I dont know if it creates any conflict with express.json() but when I commented it out it didnt make any difference.

```
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'randomstring' }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.origin + '/registerEvent',
    contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(Event.toJSONString()),
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        success = true;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        success = false;
    }
});

exports.registerEvent = function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.lastPage === '/index' && req.xhr) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

        var test = req.query.EventName;
```

Comment: How does your Express route to catch this request looks like?

Comment: var ws = require('./modules/webserv');
app.post('/registerEvent', ws.registerEvent) but its working because i can see the console.log but with an empty body

Comment: What happens if you move the bodyParser() closer to the top? Say for example, right below the 'view engine'?

Comment: contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8' seems to be causing the problem but I dont understand why. @HectorCorrea

Comment: I am baffled. Does it work if you use a different content-type?

Comment: the only thing that seems to be working is contentType: 'application/json' , the utf must be causing the problem. Although i have other ajax's (getters) that have no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data will be available in `req.body` (the parsed HTTP request body from the AJAX JSON) not `req.query` (the URL query string).

In your jquery ajax code, use `contentType: 'application/json'` and that should get it doing the kind of POST request you want.

Comment: sorry incorrect :P got a pit hyped there but req.body returns {} empty.

Comment: contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8' seems to be causing the problem but I dont understand why.

Comment: In your jquery ajax code, use `contentType: 'application/json'` and that should get it doing the kind of POST request you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a bug in Connect (the middleware that Express uses to parse the body). The code for the bodyParser uses a regular expression to match the "application/json" content type that fails when the "charset=utf-8" is appended to it.

Here is the Connect.js code that I am talking about: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/json.js#L54

The RegEx that Connect is using is

```
/^application\/([\w!#\$%&\*`\-\.\^~]*\+)?json$/i
```

If you run the following code Node you'll see that the one with "charset=utf-8" fails the test:

```
regex = /^application\/([\w!#\$%&\*`\-\.\^~]*\+)?json$/i
regex.test("application/json") // returns true
regex.test("application/json: charset=utf-8") // returns false
```

Comment: will do later and let you know, seems promising

Answer (score 0):

in my case I soveld it by this :

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code generated by Postman and it worked for me.

Instead of using my normal code

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/signup',
  data: {
    first_name: 'jacob',
    last_name: 'ross',
    username: 'username',
    emailAddress: 'email@email.com',
    password: 'somepassword'
  },
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8', // caused CORS issue
  success: function(d){
    console.log(d);
  }
})
```

I used this from Postman which worked just fine, and was able to access the params with `req.query`.

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/signup?email=email@email.com&password=123456789&first_name=jacob&last_name=ross&username=jacobrossdev",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```